# Playwright: How to uniquely identify and track frames in a page?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I would like to store my own copy of frames, using the page.on("frameattached") and page.on("framedetached") events to manage the lifecycle of my frames. But im not sure how to uniquely identify them across these events. Is the frame object passed into these listeners transient? Here is my simple use case:

```
const frames = [];
page.on("frameattached", (frame) => {
  const frame = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    url: frame.url(),
  }
  frames.push(frame);
})

page.on("framedetached", (frame) => {
  // how can i know which frame this is so i can remove it from frames[]
})
```

Comment: Aren't the `frame` objects the same across both callbacks? `frames = frames.filter(e => e !== frame)` seems like it should work. If not, are the URLs unique? A simple runnable example might make it easier to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

A `frame` object should always be the same in any event callback it's passed to. So you can simply use `===` to figure out which frame is being dealt with in a particular callback.

Here's an example. A frame is added to the array, then removed with a `===` comparison, which brings its length back to 0:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  let frames = [];
  page.on("frameattached", frame => {
    frames.push(frame);
    console.log(frames.length); // => 1
  });
  page.on("framedetached", frame => {
    frames = frames.filter(e => e !== frame);
    console.log(frames.length); // => 0
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.$eval("iframe", el => el.remove());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Feel free to experiment with this and add more frames--you'll see the array always winds up empty, assuming you remove all of the frames you add.

You can use another means of identifying a frame, like its source URL, in a way that fits your application's needs. You *generally* don't need to manage frames in most cases, so if you're still having issues making this work, you might want to add more context about what you're trying to achieve since this may not be the best way to go about it.